# Infragistics Themes not working as I expected. Default Theme not applied

Tags: angular, infragistics

It was my expectation that with a few lines of code I could include one of the Infragitics themes as explained here. (https://www.infragistics.com/products/ignite-ui-angular/angular/components/themes/examples.html)

I am working from the "Default Theme" section. I created a new Angular project using the Infragistics angular-cli. I added a button to the HTML (and supporting module imports) like this.

```
<button igxButton="raised">Sign In</button>
```

This is what I get:

[image: Pink Default Theme]

Now I follow the directions on the tutorial and add the following:

```
// import first the IgniteUI themes library
@import "~igniteui-angular/lib/core/styles/themes/index";

// Don't forget to include the igx-core first
@include igx-core();

// the default color palette is passed to the global theme
@include igx-theme($default-palette);
```

I still get the "hot pink" button seen above. However the tutorial claims and shows it to be grey. So I open the tutorial sample in StackBlitz and I become very confused.

They have manually added to the scss additional styling to get the grey effect?

```
.addProdBtn.igx-button--raised{
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    color: black;
    &:hover {
        background-color:  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26)
    }
}
```

If I take away the above scss then the sample is back to hot pink just like mine?

So I am confused. I thought the idea of the default theme was to make it easy for you to get a consistent look and feel without having to do a bunch of styling?

Comment: You're correctly pointing out that the above example you've linked has one modification on top of the default theme and it's the button above the grid. The rest of the buttons in the example are default. We will update the sample to have 0 modifications of the default theme, so it doesn't confuse users.

Answer (score 2):

I also cross posted this question on the Infragistics forums and got a response similar to Konstantin Dinev above.

The documentation is misleading and Infragistics will be updating.